# Why is jQuery a "non-MVC framework"?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to understand the "MVC" backbone.js. I came across a article that describes jQuery as a non-MVC framework, but I don't understand what that means.

I am doing all DOM manipulation using jQuery, and everything works fine.

Can anyone explain, with a simple example?

Comment: jQuery isn't a "framework" at all. It's a toolkit. It doesn't impose any particular structure on your project (which frameworks do).

Comment: MVC is just a pattern to organize your app, it's language and framework agnostic. You can do MVC with jQuery. Frameworks just help you with some nice boilerplate plus of course all the helpers and routing methods and etc that they provide.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203058/backbone-js-noob-confused-by-conflicting-tutorials/13203285#13203285

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An **MVC** framework essentially provides facilities using which you can **clearly** separate out the **M** (Model - the data), **V** (View - what your user's see) and **C** (Controller - the logic, the middle-man working with M and V) parts of your application. CakePHP, rails, and backbone (on the client side) are all examples of MVC frameworks.

**jQuery** does not do any of that. It is not a framework, it is just a collection of utils/conventions (thats an understatement by all means) to make your life a lot easier when working with JS and DOM in general.

For example, lets say you are working with an image editor, then:

- The **image** class would be your model
- The page that displays your image editor, say editor.php (or whatever) will be your view
- And the class/script that loads your image from db/disk and renders it using editor.php will be your controller
- Lets say your controller uses *libjpeg* to encode your image. *libjpeg* is just a library that helps the controller do its job well. *libjpeg* itself has nothing to do with your M, V or C.

jQuery is analogous to *libjpeg* above, it has nothing to do with how you structure your aplication, but helps your view in doing its job.

Comment: Very thanks to you. your answer is very simple and easily understandable. Now i got better understanding. very thanks to you.