# Super simple-minimal Backbone script requested

Tags: backbone.js

Looking for the absolute minimum script to get Backbone working.  Tried piecing various tutorials and sample together, but having problems getting views to work.  Nothing fancy, I'll take raw json in the browser right now. Just a basic skeleton to help connect the dots and build on. I've tried various variations on the following:

```
(function ($) {

    var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: 'custId'
    });

    var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize: function(){
        },
        model: model,
        url: '/cust'
    });

    var view = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods
            this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);

            this.render();
        },
        el: $('#content'),
        template: Handlebars.compile($("#contentTemplate").html()),
        render: function(){
            $(this.el).html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        },
        tagName: "li"
    });

    var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            var newCollection = new collection;
            newCollection.fetch();
        },
        route: {
            "": "home"
        },
        home: function(){
            this.view = new view({collection: newCollection});
            $('#content').html(this.view.el);
        }
    });

    var app = new router();
}(jQuery))
```

Thanx.

Comment: See this question on how to get started with backbone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203058/backbone-js-noob-confused-by-conflicting-tutorials/13203285#13203285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `el` attribute. `$('#content').html(this.view.el)` will result in copying the `$('#content')` element inside itself (because view.el is equal to `$('#content')`).

You should try removing the `el` attribute from the view object and let it generate itself. Then `$('#content').html(this.view.el);` should work.

One other possible problem is that you are rendering the entire collection inside a `li` element - was this what you are going for? The best way to go about this would be to have each model in the collection represent a `li` tag and the collection a `ul` tag.

Other issues:

- the `view` element is receiving a collection but you are trying to render a model
- in the router, `newCollection` is not accessible in the home method
- You are not calling `Backbone.history.start()`

Here is how i would rewrite the code:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'custId'
});

var model_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile($("#modelTemplate").html()),
    tagName: 'li',
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
        this.on('change',this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        return this;
    }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
    },
    model: model,
    url: '/cust'
});

var collection_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render','renderModels');
        this.render();
        this.renderModels();
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.renderModels);
    },
    render: function(){
        // just create the 'ul' tag; we will populate it with model view elements; a collection template is no longer needed
        return this;
    },
    renderModels: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(obj){
            var view = new model_view({
                model: obj
            });
            $(this.el).append(view.el);
        },this);
    }
});

var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.newCollection = new collection();
        this.newCollection.fetch();
    },
    route: {
        "": "home"
    },
    home: function(){
        this.view = new collection_view({collection: this.newCollection});
        $('#content').html(this.view.el); // #content should not be a 'ul' tag, the 'ul' is generated by the collection_view
    }
});

var app = new router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Make sure you update your templates accordingly.

Please excuse possible errors, i had no means to test the code but i believe it points out the logic you should use.

Cheers!

Comment: Suggestions: use [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) instead of `$(this.el)`, `render` should probably call `renderModels` so that you don't have to worry about binding order vs calling order. Those are pretty minor points though.

Comment: Weeee!!! It does something. Error in router route needs to be routes which made Backbone.history.start undefined.  Your 1st point--I think that was a mistake from desparatly trying to get it to work.  Didn't realize I didn't have to define el.  Didn't realize I had to iterate collection, thought the framework automagically handled that.  Thanx!

Comment: Successfully ported a jquery-tmpl based "view" from my SPA to Backbone. Sweet. Close to getting a grip. Thanx.